# MaterialUI images list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to recreate this design using MUI in React
[image: team members images list]

I just want to know if there are some mui components/ techniques that I can use to get the display of the images shown in the screenshot above, any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I Used The Stack Component and gave it a negative spacing,
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/